# mocked function returns null after specifying return

Tags: java, junit, mockito

The test code

```
    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    private ServiceClient client;

    @Test
    public void getDocument() throws IOException {
        String fileExtension = "fileextension";
        String host = "docserverurl";
        String path = "path";
        String content = "content";

        client = new ServiceClient(restTemplate, host, fileExtension);
        when(restTemplate.getForEntity(any(), any()))
                .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity(content, HttpStatus.OK));
        assertEquals(content, new String(client.getDocument(path)));
    }
```

and the code under test

```
    public byte[] getDocument(String path) throws IOException {
        path = suffixWithExtension(path);
        return restTemplate.getForEntity(docServiceHost + DOC_SERVICE_API_VERSION_DEFAULT + DOCUMENT + path, byte[].class).getBody();
    }
```

For some reason, I'm running into an issue where when the `getForEntity` function is called in the function under test , it returns null instead of the mocked response.

Comment: What happens when `getBody()` is called on a new `ResponseEntity`?  That's what the code ought to be doing.

Comment: it gets the body from the response. What happens when it's being tested? It throws a null exception

Comment: Are you sure that throws the exception and not the restTemplate is null?

Comment: Another possibility is that `RestTemplate` is `final`, which means you can't mock it.

Comment: @SzigyártóMihály yes when I set the debugger on the line restTemplate is not shown as null

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem rest template is not final

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem That's clearly not the solution. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. This should work.

```
byte[] content = "content".getBytes();
when(restTemplate.getForEntity(anyString(), any()))
                .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity(content, HttpStatus.OK));
final byte[] sds = someClass.getDocument("sd");
assertEquals(new String(content), new String(sds));
```

Some tips. If you are doing this

```
client = new ServiceClient(restTemplate, host, fileExtension);
```

you do not need `@InjectMocks`.  It is redundant. It is a best practice to use Constructor Injections and not use Field Injections and `@InjectMocks`.

I hope you are Mocks are initialized. This is done with

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

This is also done via some Runner classes(If you are using any)

Comment: I am using `MockitoJUnitRunner`, thank you for the tips!